# Which dialects of English consider "would" to be a polite form of "will"?

Tags: politeness, dialects, conditionals, will-would

My recent trip to India exposed me to many sentences using "would" as a polite substitute for "will", as in

> Please make sure to leave on time. The last bus would depart at 8PM.
>
> Thanks for checking out early. However, there would be no refund.

I am not familiar with such patterns in AmE or BE. Are they common in particular settings that I'm not aware of? How common are they in India?

Note: the following query seems to return a bunch of other examples (among conditional uses of course) `inurl:.co.in "would"`

Comment: Those two examples of yours sound off to my native ear. Where did you get them from? Perhaps you are thinking of the difference between *“Will you get out of my way?”* versus the softened *“Would you please get out of my way?”* — neither of which is “conditional”, of course.

Comment: What @tchrist said. Unless OP's example usages are common in *India* (which seems unlikely to me), I think there are probably *no* "dialects" where they'd be seen as "polite alternatives". All they indicate to me is "not a native speaker".

Comment: I wonder if this could perhaps be an extension of the subjunctive? Perhaps a hypercorrection? I'd want more examples before suggesting that as an answer.

Comment: The OP already stated it did not seem like AmE or BrE, but that he had seen/ heard it in India. I'm not from India, and unless any of you commenters are, or know Indian dialects of English, these comments (including mine) are not responsive, only conjecture.

Comment: I have heard this construction in Indian English - not all that frequently, though certainly more frequently than in AmE. I think it probably is a hypercorrection, perhaps related to the fact that it is politer to use "could"/"would" rather than "can"/"will" when making requests.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Without personal experience of India, I'm not sure why one would assume this couldn't be a common usage there.

Comment: @Chris Sunami: It's my understanding that an awful lot of IE speakers would say *"The bus is departing at 8pm"*, whereas practically all other Anglophones would say *"The bus **departs** at 8pm"*. But I believe most "careful" IE speakers would rather adopt US/UK usage standards whenever they discover that a construction they've been used to using actually marks them out as IE rather than "standard English" speakers. I'm not aware that any IE variants are "officially" endorsed or "deliberately" taught.

Comment: There are a lot of cases where "will" and "would" can be interchanged in English, sometimes with no substantial change in meaning, sometimes with a subtle change in the "imperativeness" of the sentence.  It would be incredibly hard to come up with any sort of comprehensive rules.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps not, but it's been an official language there since 1965, and is the first language for 100,000 Indians, so it's far from unlikely that it has developed into a unique dialect, especially given the influence on it of other Indian languages. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English

Comment: @@Chris Sunami: The number of "native" IE speakers is vanishingly small compared to those who use it regularly as a *lingua franca*. And so far as I know, the "English" as endorsed by officialdom is either UK (or increasingly nowadays, US) standard. It just so happens that there are a number of significant deviations from those standard for various reasons, but I find it hard to believe anyone actually *endorses* the "non-standard" variants.

Comment: @JonHanna Hypercorrection sounds like a likely explanation.

Comment: As a native speaker of Indian English, I can confirm that a large number of Indians use _would_ in place of _will_. I can also confirm that this is still considered nonstandard, even in India, which means there is still a large enough population using the currently considered correct versions of _will_ and _would_. Linguists I've spoken to think this phenomenon of using _would_ in place of _will_ has come about because ESL learners are taught that using _would_ is more polite than _will_ (e.g., _Would you like some coffee?_).

Comment: @Tragicomic: Thanks for sharing your experience; this could be appropriate material for an answer!

Comment: Of course, this causes all sorts of confusion when people from India interact with people from other parts of the world. A colleague of mine missed a deadline because a counterpart of his in the U.S. said, "I would send the report today." My colleague assumed this meant that the U.S. employee would send the report, since he (my colleague) took _would_ to mean the same thing as _will_.

Comment: @Clement: I was hoping to find some references I could direct you to, but there don't appear to be any. I suppose experience as a speaker of Indian English living in India is the closest we'll get to an answer. Some day a PhD scholar will write a thesis on "Use of modal verbs in Indian English" and then we'll have our reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native speaker of Indian English, I can confirm that a large number of Indians use *would* in place of *will*. I can also confirm that this is still considered nonstandard, even in India, which means there is still a large enough population using *will* and *would* in the sense currently considered correct/accepted. Linguists I've spoken to think this phenomenon of using *would* in place of *will* has come about because ESL learners are taught that using *would* is more polite than *will* (e.g., *Would you like some coffee?*).

This can cause some confusion when people from India interact with people from other parts of the world. A colleague of mine missed a deadline because a counterpart of his in the U.S. said, "I would send the report today." My colleague assumed this meant that the U.S. employee would send the report, since he (my colleague) took *would* to mean the same thing as *will*.

Answer (score 2):

I just asked one of my friends from India and she confirmed the use of 'would' instead of 'will'. She said that it is very common in India. However, she thinks that most people do not use 'would' to be polite. She said that 'will' and 'would' are interchangeable in India. Finally, the use of 'would' to express the future other than in past sentences seems to be endemic to India. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You would only use "there would be no refund" when describing conditional situation, i.e. "you could check out early but there would be no refund".

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: So if the question is "how common is this", I don't know, but more people saying it doesn't make it grammatically correct!

Comment: Actually, more people saying something is the **only** thing that will ever make anything grammatically correct. And the question _was_ quite specifically whether this use of _would_ to mark politeness, though quite nonexistent in BrE and AmE, are in fact in common usage somewhere.

Answer (score -2):

it's not about dialect. they hold barely different meanings.

would - would stand for "if that particular thing happened/happens, then it Would.. (it might be.. it could be..)

whereas

will - is a helper verb to form a sense of future tense.

Comment: No, not in this case. These were definitely references to things in the future.